# Is it unnecessary to verify the same methods as the methods being mocked in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I often see the same methods being verified as the methods being mocked in `Mockito` (example below). Is there any added benefit to call `Mockito.verify()` in these cases?

```
//mock method
FooService fs = mock(FooService.class);
when(fs.getFoo()).thenReturn("foo");

//method under test
fs.doSomething();

//verify method
verify(fs).getFoo();
```

The method should fail if `fs.getFoo()` is not called. So why call `verify`? I see the benefit if you need to use `ArgumentCaptor` in the verify to assert the parameters; besides the ArgumentCaptor case, is it just unnecessary?

Comment: I would say it is necessary, because what if you suddenly change your `doSomething()` to not call `getFoo()` anymore or just comment it?. How would you get to know about that if you haven't verified the method invocation.

Comment: @TajAhmed Isn't there a way to make the test fail if the mocked method isn't called without doing `verify()`?

Comment: It is kind of possible when you are using the output of mocked method in you testing class method. Then you can just verify that mocked data is prepared by asserting the return value.Doing this may/may not be possible depending on whether your tesing method is returing any value or not. So i would recommend using verify which gives assurity of method getting called.

Comment: I think you should use the term "stubbed" instead of "mocked" for `Mockito.when` ( see http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2 ).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Mockito documentation repeatedly says it is often redundant. This appears verbatim both in [`verify(T)`'s Javadoc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2) as multiple single-line comments in the code block in [Mockito's main class Javadoc section 2](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2):

> Although it is possible to verify a stubbed invocation, usually it's just redundant.
> If your code cares what `get(0)` returns, then something else breaks (often even before `verify()` gets executed).
> If your code doesn't care what `get(0)` returns, then it should not be stubbed. Not convinced? See [here](https://szczepiq.wordpress.com/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling/).

Note that the originally linked article, "[Asking and Telling](https://szczepiq.wordpress.com/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling/)", was written by Mockito originator Szczepan Faber and can be considered an authoritative document in Mockito's design. To excerpt from that post:

> Do I really have to repeat the same expression? After all, stubbed interactions are **verified implicitly**. The execution flow of my own code does it **completely for free**. [Aaron Jensen](http://codebetter.com/blogs/aaron.jensen/archive/2008/04/03/separate-stub-and-verify-duplicate-code-necessarily.aspx) also noticed that:
>
> > If you’re verifying you don’t need to stub unless of course that method returns something that is critical to the flow of your test (or code), in which case you don’t really need to verify, because the flow would have verified.
>
> Just to recap: **there is no repeated code**.
>
> But what if an interesting interaction **shares the characteristic of both asking and telling?** Do I have to repeat interactions in stub() and verify()? Will I end up with duplicated code? Not really. In practice: **If I stub** then it is verified for free, so **I don’t verify**. **If I verify** then I don’t care about the return value, so **I don’t stub**. Either way, [**I don’t repeat myself**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). In theory though, I can imagine a rare case where I do verify a stubbed interaction, for example to make sure the stubbed interaction happened exactly n times. But this is a different aspect of behavior and apparently an interesting one. Therefore I want to be explicit and I am perfectly happy to sacrifice one extra line of code…

Recent versions of Mockito (released since this Q&A was posted) have added some additional features that [allow](http://blog.mockito.org/2017/01/clean-tests-produce-clean-code-strict.html) or [default to](http://blog.mockito.org/2018/07/new-mockito-api-lenient.html) stricter mocking styles. Despite this, the prevailing expectation is to avoid brittleness by only verifying what you can't confirm through assertions or successful test completion.

Overall, Mockito's design is to allow tests to be as flexible as possible,  coding not to the implementation but instead to the spec of the method you're testing. Though you'll occasionally see a method call as part of a function's spec ("Submits an RPC to the server" or "Calls the passed LoginCallback immediately"), it's much more likely that you'll want to validate the postconditions that you can infer from the stubs: Checking that `getFoo` was called isn't really a part of the spec as long as you stubbed `getFoo` to return "foo" and the data store contains a single object with its corresponding property set to "foo".

---

In short, it is considered good Mockito style to explicitly verify only the interactions that can't be implied from well-crafted stubs and postcondition assertions. They may be good calls for otherwise-unmeasurable side effects—logging code, thread executors, ArgumentCaptors, multiple method calls, callback functions—but generally should not be applied to stubbed interactions.

Comment: "Asking and Telling" Link is no longer valid.
I'm confused without it as the point of the test is to test that unexpected changes in code should fail the test. And this concept seems to sacrifice it for less verbal tests?
Many other mocking frameworks does both tasks with one line of code, not requiring duplication.

Comment: @EatonEmmerich I've updated the link. Mockito's original opinion as a framework was that unexpected code changes should *not* automatically fail the test, since a good test should not be a change-detector, it should just hold the implementation to its own specification even as the implementation evolves. It was possible to have mocks "strict by default" as it was in Mockito's inspiration/ancestor EasyMock, but Mockito deliberately diverged for that reason. Mockito's newer concept of "lenience" does modify that original vision since I wrote my answer, but it's more than I could edit in tonight.

Comment: I dug up the "Asking and Telling" article link. Looks like the domain of Faber's old blog changed which is obscured by the fact that he has a new blog that doesn't include these older posts. https://szczepiq.wordpress.com/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling/

Comment: @Planky Thanks, yes. The URL schema changed a bit, but the post is still up. I've edited the fresh one back in.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific example you give (which is not really a complete example, but it's good enough to make your question clear), I see no reason to verify the call which is stubbed.

I think it's good design to *verify* calls which are intended to have side effects and to *stub* calls (using `when`) which are intended to provide data. Doing both makes the design less clear and the test a little less readable, in most cases.

If a call which provides data and has no side effects receives as an argument values which are generated or modified by the method under test (for example, a key synthesized to retrieve a value), then verification *might* be useful (even when the arguments are simple enough that you do not need `ArgumentCaptor`). You can stub with specific arguments or custom matchers, which is probably good enough to test such a case (for example `when(fs.getFoo("generatedKey1234")).thenReturn("foo1234")`), but checking the argument(s) in `verify` could enhance the readability of the test - so it's a judgment call.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the sentence "If a call which provides data and has no side effects receives as an argument values.." I didn't understand that part.

Comment: If your method under test (let's call it the MUT) calls a collaborator's getter method (like `getFoo()` in your example), you just need to stub the getter to verify that the MUT behaves as expected.  If the MUT calls a collagorator to retrieve a value based on an argument passed in to the MUT (for example retrieving a user from storage based on a username passed in to the MUT), that's also a clear case for stubbing, because the MUT just takes what was given and uses it to get data from a collaborator.

Comment: Continuing my coment above, the case which is not clear to you: the MUT doesn't just take the arguments received and pass them to a colaborator but actually MODIFIES them or generates them or gets them from a collaborator.  The MUT creates or retrieves at least one value which it did not have before it was called and uses that value to retrieve data from a colaborator (which is mocked for the test).  In that case, you need to verify that the newly created/retrieved value (which itself is not returned by the MUT) is correctly created or retrieved.