# Using Mockito.when() to mock and verify vs mockito.verify

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Imagine you have method **someMethod**, how would you go by to test it?

```java
Mockito.when(someClass.someMethod(someParam)).thenReturn(someValue);
var bar = foo() // SUT: ends upp calling someMethod somewhere in the stack
assertThat(bar).isEqualTo(someValue);
```

vs

```java
Mockito.when(someClass.someMethod(someParam)).thenReturn(someValue);
var bar = foo() // SUT: ends upp calling someMethod somewhere in the stack
verify(someClass, times(1)).someMethod(someParam)
assertThat(bar).isEqualTo(someValue);
```

It is true that the **Mockito.when** is "kind of" verifying that **someClass.someMethod** is being called with the correct arguments. Personally I like the idea of having clear assertions/verifications so that the tests can serve as a form of documentation. I don't like giving my mocks double-responsibilities, I want to keep my mocks just simply as "mocks".
So back to my question.

What is the preferred way, using **Mockito.when** combined with **Mockito.verify** or only **Mockito.when**?

Comment: They both serve different purposes. `Mockito.when()` only create the mock when a method with the given argument is called. If the argument won't match no mock will be created. `Mockito.verify()` checks how often a method was called before this line. Whereas the assert statement controls the value of the parameter.

Comment: Yes @FaltFe however if you use `Mockito.when()` with the right arguments, then the test will fail if the tested method doesn't call the mocked method with the correct arguments, therefore theoretically speaking, it can be used as a verification of the method arguments as well. Therefore my question.

Comment: I think I start getting the point. But when you don't need the mock why writing it? Shouldn't you keep the test short and clean? I would suggest using `ArgumentCaptor` to check the passed argument. And instead of using `times()` there are some other options like `verifyZeroInteractions()`.

Comment: Mocks are not tests per se - they are used to facilitate testing, permitting you to replace a component with one which has defined behaviour

Comment: @FaltFe there are interactions with the mock so the `Mockito,when()` is still required. So in this case the `Mockito.verify()` is a bit redundant as the test will still fail without it if the **someMethod** don't get called with the correct arguments, because then the mock won't work.

Answer (score 1):

When defines the behaviour of the Mock - declaratively defining the way the mock will respond when methods are invoked with different parameters.
Verify is used to check whether the Mock has been interacted with in various ways.

Here are some URLS to the official Mockito documentation, which I hope will help.

- [Stubbing - with when](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing)
- [Argument matchers](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers)
- [Verification in order](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#in_order_verification)
- [Making sure interaction(s) never happened
  on mock](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#never_verification)

It's probably worth performing a search for some other examples.

Comment: `//Although it is possible to verify a stubbed invocation, usually it's just redundant`

This is exactly what I'm talking about. It is redundant yes. So question is, should I let it be redundant or count on the stubbed method to do the verification? The problem I see is, if a new developer reads the test, they won't know the subbed method is part of the verification process. It's like using Given, When, Then but without the Then part, because the test won't work without the When anyways. So it's abusing the mock method in my eyes. Opinions on this?

Comment: It's sometime useful to ensure that the interaction during the test is occurring as intended. For example, the injected Mock might have some calls you have not anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35301264/473064.

The summary is:

> In short, it is considered good Mockito style to explicitly verify only the interactions that can't be implied from well-crafted stubs and postcondition assertions. They may be good calls for otherwise-unmeasurable side effects—logging code, thread executors, ArgumentCaptors, multiple method calls, callback functions—but generally should not be applied to stubbed interactions.

One point that I would add is that sometimes if we want to do a `verifyZeroInterations` to ensure that no unexpected calls occurred, we would have to first exhaust the known calls by `verify`ing them.

What I usually do is to perform the simplest `verify(mock, times(n)).someMethod(anyClass())` as generally as possible without repeating the more specific argument matching that I have already specified in the stubbing, which reduces the duplication as much as possible.

Example:

```
when(someObject.someMethod(eq("abc"))).thenReturn(someValue);
when(someObject.someMethod(eq("def"))).thenReturn(otherValue);
when(someObject.someMethod(endsWith("suffix"))).thenReturn(anotherValue);

var bar = foo();

assertEquals(expectedBar, bar);

verify(someObject, times(3)).someMethod(anyString());
verifyZeroInteractions(someObject);
```

Regarding your concern in the comment:

> The problem I see is, if a new developer reads the test, they won't know the subbed method is part of the verification process.

The stubbed method is not part of the verification process. It's part of the test case setup, i.e., the `Given` step.

I think your example might be a little bit misleading. The final output from `foo()` is usually a transformation of the response from `someMethod`, i.e.,  `someValue` in the example. So if the stubbed method is not called and returned with the correct value, the test would have failed anyway. The said developer would then have to look at the mocking and understand how the test case works.

In the updated example below, there is no need to verify that `someMethod` is called because if it didn't get called, the assertion would fail.

```
Mockito.when(someClass.someMethod(someParam)).thenReturn(someValue);
var bar = foo() // SUT: ends upp calling someMethod somewhere in the stack
var expectedValue = // a value depending on `someValue`
assertThat(bar).isEqualTo(expectedValue);
```